# c++ anonymous constructor doing weird things

Tags: c++, anonymous, default-constructor

This sample program shows how a different constructor will be called depending on whether you pass in a local variable, a global variable, or an anonymous variable. What is going on here?

```
std::string globalStr;
class aClass{
public:
  aClass(std::string s){
    std::cout << "1-arg constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  aClass(){
    std::cout << "default constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  void puke(){
    std::cout << "puke" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  std::string localStr;
  //aClass(localStr); //this line does not compile
  aClass(globalStr);  //prints "default constructor"
  aClass(""); //prints "1-arg constructor"
  aClass(std::string("")); //also prints "1-arg constructor"
  globalStr.puke(); //compiles, even though std::string cant puke.
}
```

Given that I can call `globalStr.puke()`, I'm guessing that by calling `aClass(globalStr);`, it is creating a local variable named `globalStr` of type `aClass` that is being used instead of the global `globalStr`. Calling `aClass(localStr);` tries to do the same thing, but fails to compile because `localStr` is already declared as a `std::string`. Is it possible to create an anonymous instance of a class by calling its 1-arg constructor with a non-constant expression? Who decided that `type(variableName);` should be an acceptable way to define a variable named `variableName`?

Comment: What's an _anonymous constructor_?? There's no such thing I'm aware of.

Comment: [Well, that's interesting](http://ideone.com/eNXYvI), why can `puke()` be called on a `std::string` class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, It's shadowed by the declaration of `globalStr` in `main`.

Comment: This is one of the best motivations I've seen for using `{..}` for constructing objects rather than `(..)`.

Comment: @chris I can't spot the shadowed declaration, help me out please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `aClass(globalStr)`

Comment: C++ (and C, for that matter) allows you to put parenthesis around identifiers when declaring them. This syntax is in fact needed when declaring function pointers: `aClass (*fptr)(std::string)`

Comment: I wish strings _could_ puke.

Comment: @paddy, Too bad the UFCS proposal only went in one way then. No defining `void puke(std::string)` and calling `someString.puke();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
aClass(localStr); //this line does not compile
```

This tries to declare a variable of type `aClass` named `localStr`. The syntax is terrible, I agree, but it's way too late for that [changing the standard] now.

```
aClass(globalStr);  //prints "default constructor"
```

This declares one called `globalStr`. This `globalStr` variable hides the global one.

```
aClass(""); //prints "1-arg constructor"
```

This creates a temporary object of type `aClass`.

```
aClass(std::string("")); //also prints "1-arg constructor"
```

This also creates a temporary.

```
globalStr.puke(); //compiles, even though std::string cant puke.
```

This uses the `globalStr` in `main`, which is consistent with every other instance of shadowing.

> Is it possible to create an anonymous instance of a class by calling its 1-arg constructor with a non-constant expression?

Yes, I can think of four ways:

```
aClass{localStr}; // C++11 list-initialization, often called "uniform initialization"
(void)aClass(localStr); // The regular "discard this result" syntax from C.
void(aClass(localStr)); // Another way of writing the second line with C++.
(aClass(localStr)); // The parentheses prevent this from being a valid declaration.
```

---

As a side note, this syntax can often be the cause of the Most Vexing Parse. For example, the following declares a function `foo` that returns `aClass`, with one parameter `localStr` of type `std::string`:

```
aClass foo(std::string(localStr));
```

Indeed it's the same rule that's responsible for your problems - If something can be parsed as a valid declaration, it must be. That is why `aClass(localStr);` is a declaration and not a statement consisting of a lone expression.